# java \n is printed, should break line?

Tags: java, string

I have a string that when it see's `\n` it should break line. However when I print it too screen it actually shows the \n as characters.

1. My file has a line such as q1. what is your name? `\n` a.bob `\n` b.jim
2. I then store that result into a String when its read from the file
3. I then send it over RMI to a client which it is then displayed. It should be

   q1. what is your name?

   ```
   a. bob
   b. jim
   ```

However it all is printed on one line exactly how it is in the file.

code of it reading from file and returning back to client

```
    String [] line = new String [10];
            try 
            {
                int i =0;
                for (i=0;i<=9;i++)
                {
                    line[i] = "";
                }
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("questions.txt"));
                scanner.useDelimiter("Q");
                i=0;
                while (scanner.hasNext()) 
                {
                    line[i] = scanner.next();
                    //System.out.println("" + line[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            }
return line[0]; //return string back to client
```

Comment: You need to show us the code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself.

Comment: FWIW, your original file with no \n strings present actually already contains a newline character to split the lines.  you should take a hex editor and look at the hex codes in your file to prove this to yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\n` behaves like a control character only when you add it to a Java string yourself. When reading from the file the `\` is read literally i.e. it gets escaped as `\\` and the following `n` is then interpreted as `n` only.

So, if you want the *literal* `\n` to be interpreted as a *newline* by your client, you would have to replace it before return as

```
return line[0].replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
```

Comment: Ah Brilliant. Never knew thats how it worked! Thanks